# Remove all before comma in items of array Python

Tags: python

there is an array:

```
[['Frog', 4298], ['Bear', 2106], ['Bee', 6110], ['Zombie', 2749]]
```

Need output array:

```
[[4298], [2106], [6110], [2749]]
```

Maybe somebody can help me.

Comment: `[[l[1]] for l in lst]`